# Types of predicate and existence

Tags: metaphysics

Is there a term for properties that cannot be predicated of existing things. Or one for properties that can?

Answer (score 2):

See [The Epistemology of Modality](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-epistemology/). We can sey that the first one are (logical or metaphysical) *impossible* properties, while the second one are *possible*.

Comment: ah! Interesting idea.

Comment: hi again... so a property that can only be predicated of things that don't exist is metaphysically impossible?

Comment: @user3293056 - of course, is only a sugegstion. May we say that the property of *being faster than light* is phyiscally impossible, while the property of *being higher than itself* is logically impossible. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Note though, that there's an important debate about whether properties are sparse or abundant. (Roughly, abundant property theorists say every true subject/predicate sentence has a property in virtue of which it is true. "Socrates is bald" is true because the object Socrates has the property `baldness`) If you take a sparse property view, on the other hand, you wouldn't want to say that there were things like impossible properties, I think. Perhaps somebody who knows more can correct me though.